# Example of 2 related angular ui-grids

Tags: jquery, angularjs

After a few days researching I am in stack with problem of how to link 2 ui-grids. I need to have 2 grids on one page. Based on selected item on 1st grid, 2nd grid should immediately filter data by linked column.

here is index.html

```
    <div class="col-md-3 block" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridTypesOptions" ui-grid-selection class="typegrid"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 block" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridMainOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit class="grid"></div>
    <br>
    <strong>Data Length:</strong> {{ gridMainOptions.data.length | number }}
    <br>
    <strong>Last Cell Edited:</strong> {{msg.lastCellEdited}}
    <br>
</div>
```

next block is main.js

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.rowEdit', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.selection']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.selectedType = [];
    $scope.gridTypesOptions = {
        columnDefs: [{ name: 'journal_name', enableCellEdit: false, displayName: 'Journal Name', width: '100%' }],
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedType,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
        noUnselect: false,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                var filterData = row.entity.journal_name;
                console.log(filterData);
                $scope.selectedType = [{ filterData }];

                gridApi.grid.refresh();
            });
        }
    }

    $http.get('/home/types')
      .success(function (data) {
          $scope.gridTypesOptions.data = data;
    });

    $scope.gridMainOptions = {
        useExternalFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        columnDefs: [
      { name: 'journal_id', displayName: 'Id', type: 'number', enableCellEdit: false, width: '10%' },
      {
          name: 'journal_name', displayName: 'Type', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', width: '10%',
          cellFilter: 'mapType', editDropdownValueLabel: 'journal_name', editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath: 'typeOptions'
          //filter: {term: $scope.selectedType.toString()}
      },
      { name: 'journal_name_20', displayName: 'Name (20 chars)', width: '20%' },
      { name: 'journal_name_max', displayName: 'Name (max chars)', width: '24%' },
      { name: 'journal_qty', displayName: 'Qty', type: 'number', width: '8%' },
      { name: 'journal_price', displayName: 'Price', cellFilter: 'currency', width: '8%' },
      { name: 'journal_date', displayName: 'Date', type: 'date', enableCellEdit: false, cellFilter: 'date:"dd.MM.yy"', width: '20%' }
        ],

    };

    $scope.msg = {};
    $scope.gridMainOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

        gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, function(rowEntity){
                var promise = $scope.SaveRowData(rowEntity);
                $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, promise.promise);
                $scope.gridApi.grid.queueGridRefresh();
        });

        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'Edited row id:' + rowEntity.journal_id + ' Column:' + colDef.displayName + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue;
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
            var grid = this.grid;

            angular.forEach(grid.columns, function (value, key) {
                if (value.filters[0].term) {
                    console.log('FILTER TERM FOR ' + value.colDef.name + ' = ' + value.filters[0].term);
                }
            });

            this.grid.refresh();
        });

        gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
    };

    $http.get('/home/data')
      .success(function (data) {
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              data[i].journal_date = new Date(data[i].journal_date);
              data[i].journal_name = data[i].journal_type.journal_name;
              data[i].typeOptions = $scope.gridTypesOptions.data;
          }
          $scope.gridMainOptions.data = data;
      });


    $scope.filter = function () {
        $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
    };

    $scope.singleFilter = function () {
        console.log('Column value: ' + $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[1] + 'Selected type: ' + selectedType);
        $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[1].filter.term = selectedType;
    };

    $scope.SaveRowData = function (row) {
        var rowdata = row;
        return $.post("home/setdata", rowdata, function (data) {
        });
    }
}])

.filter('mapType', function () {
    var typeHash = {
        'system 1' : 'system 1',
        'system 2': 'system 2',
        'user 1': 'user 1',
        'user 2': 'user 2',
    };
    return function (input) {
        if (!input) {
            return ' - ';
        } else {
            return typeHash[input];
        }
    };
})

.filter('currency', function () { 
    return function (value) {
        return '$' + value
            .toFixed(2)
            .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    }
})
;
```

Any idea of how this may work?

Comment: Would be very helpful if you could provide a plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example http://plnkr.co/edit/03BEDS1QAj2UVsvjPxUS?p=preview

JS:
Here gridApi refers to 1st grid and gridApi1 refers to 2nd grid.

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
   console.log(row.entity);
   $scope.gridApi1.grid.columns[1].filters[0].term = row.entity.name;
});
```

PS: It is always good to post a plunkr link instead of pasting code.

Comment: Thanks. That's it.